# Strange redirecting with koala gem

Tags: ruby, facebook, sinatra, koala

I'm using ruby, sinatra, and the koala gem to create an app for facebook.
When I redirect to /auth/facebook It does what is needed, however it first redirects to a page with this rectangle, then goes to the auth dialog. I think this is very ugly for the end user. How can I remove this strange redirection?
[image: Screenshot]
Code:

```
#This function defines a get and post route with the same parameters.
def get_or_post(path, opts={}, &block)
  get(path, opts, &block)
  post(path, opts, &block)
end

get "/auth/facebook/?" do
  redirect authenticator.url_for_oauth_code(:permissions => FACEBOOK_SCOPE)
end

get_or_post '/auth/facebook/callback/?' do
  session[:access_token] = authenticator.get_access_token(params[:code])
  update_user()
  redirect '/'
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are doing the redirect inside of the canvas iframe? That of course would try to display the auth dialog inside of that iframe, and the auth dialog does *not want* to be displayed in any kind of (i)frame.

So instead of redirecting (where you can not specify a *target*), use JavaScript to “redirect” – have your script put out a small HTML document, that basically just contains one line of JavaScript, that uses

```
top.location.href = '{auth dialog URL goes here}';
```

to load a new URL in the *top frame* of the current browser window.

Comment: Interesting. I am, in some places, using a server-side authentication flow. This means that I'm redirecting to my Authentication URL from the server-side code. In order to avoid this issue, I have to use the Client-side (JS) authentication flow, correct?

Comment: No, not necessarily – you just have to make sure the server-side auth dialog does not get called inside any (i)frames, but in the top window instance.

Comment: This is true, but since I am making a facebook app the server-side stuff will _always_ get called innside an iframe.

Comment: Yes, but as I said you can use JavaScript instead of an HTTP redirect, to get the target URL displayed in the correct window; but doing so would not make your whole Auth flow become the client-side one – it’ll still be the _server-side_ Auth flow, and JS is only used to make it happen in the right place.

Comment: Yep, makes sense. I'm going to make a oneliner html template and pass the redirect url from the Koala Gem to it. Easy fix, thanks!